# Whats the basic purpose of OperationContext in table.Execute in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Whats the basic purpose of OperationContext in table.Execute command while inserting data  in Azure Table Storage?

I happen to see the table.Execute  command having parameter called OperationContext ...Whats the purpose of it..and also I see the OperationContext  class has 2 events

```
`opContext.SendingRequest += opContext_SendingRequest;
opContext.ResponseReceived+=opContext_ResponseReceived;`
```

whats the purpose of it...what it helps in the table.Execute command
.?...If any examples deeply Appriciates....

Comment: http://oleksiionsoftware.com/post/07-azure-queue-with-net-console-app-operation-context

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext_members.aspx) states:

> Represents the context for a request to the storage service and
>   provides additional runtime information about its execution.

While mostly it can be used to track service execution (like how much time the request took etc.), one important thing here is that you can pass something specific to your environment in `ClientRequestID` field and that gets persisted in storage analytics logs so that you can do better tracing of requests and correlate it with your system logging.